# Item added to ActionBar programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm tring to add the Search item to my ActionBar. I wrote this code.

```
@Override
     public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
         menu.add(0, 1, Menu.NONE, "Search").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

         searchView = (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(1));

         searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

         });

     }
```

But when i run the app crash with this error

```
11-23 14:17:45.294: E/AndroidRuntime(28399): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference
```

Okay, the logcat says that searchView is null but why? His id is 1 and i find the item with findItem method passing the id of the item that is 1. How can i solve?

P.S. I'm in a Fragment.

Comment: why you want to put Search in your action bar programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Your menu item doesn't have the `android.widget.SearchView` action class assigned to it, and therefore you get null from the `getActionView()` call. Basically, you're missing the code equivalent of the `android:actionViewClass` attribute from [this example](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html#add-sv) in the Android docs.

You can use the `setActionView` method of `MenuItem` to add it.

Another thing: you're not really supposed to just make up ID numbers in code, because the resource system can't prevent number clashes that way. You'll want to put a `<item type="id" name="menu_search"/>` in one of your values XML files and replace the all the `1`s by `R.id.menu_search`.